# I don’t understand how the code is getting 56, 49

Tags: python, if-statement, range

```
num = 0
even = 0
odd = 0

for num in range(0, 15):
    if (num /2 == int(num /2)):
        even += num
    else:
        odd += num
print("even:",even,"odd:",odd,"num:",num)
```

I'm baffled on how I'm getting the results, can someone please break it down for me?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? You are generating the sums of odd and even numbers in your range

Comment: Stack Overflow questions should be narrow and specific. Describing what you think it _should_ get instead, and why, would help. Right now it's unclear what makes the current output unexpected.

Comment: Why don't you use `num % 2 == 0`  condition if `num` is even then condition will be `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program is adding the sums of all even and odd numbers between 0-14.
This is what going behind for loop:

```
num=0, if-statement (true), even=0+0=0
num=1, else-statement (true), odd=0+1=0;
num=2, if-statement (true), even=0+2=2
num=3, else-statement (true), odd=1+3=4;
num=4, if-statement (true), even=2+4=6
num=5, else-statement (true), odd=4+5=9;
num=6, if-statement (true), even=6+6=12
num=7, else-statement (true), odd=9+7=16;
num=8, if-statement (true), even=12+8=20
num=9, else-statement (true), odd=16+9=25;
num=10, if-statement (true), even=20+10=30
num=11, else-statement (true), odd=25+11=36;
num=12, if-statement (true), even=30+12=42
num=13, else-statement (true), odd=36+13=49;
num=14, if-statement (true), even=42+14=56
```

Comment: Thank you everyone who chimed in. And thank you Burhan for letting me see what is going on in the loop. This was for a code that I had to analyze and figure out the output. When I ran the code I seen the output, but I was clueless as to how I got it. Thank you again!